# Application timeout in ASP.NET Core 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

1. Is there a way to set the application timeout in ASP.NET Core 1/MVC 6?
2. What is the default time a site stays in memory without
   activity on the site, haven't been able to locate documentation on
   this?

I can see when the site spins up from the text log of the stdout but I'm not sure when it goes down or how I can extend (or shrink) that number programatically.

Comment: What do you mean by application timeout ? Regarding your 2nd question, it's depend how you host it, it is an IIS worker process setting if you host it in IIS.

Comment: In my case I'm using IIS and hosting it via the platform handler.  As for application timeout I mean when the site goes out of memory from non use (where things like classes added by AddInstance or memory cache items go *poof*).

Comment: I recommend reading this thread: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way to set the application timeout in ASP.NET Core 1/MVC 6?

I don't think so. Application timeouts would be set by the host ([IIS example](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx)).

> 2. What is the default time a site stays in memory without activity on the site, haven't been able to locate documentation on this?

Again, this depends on the host. For IIS, the default time is 20 minutes. When you're debugging with Visual Studio, I'm not sure if it will timeout.

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like if hosted through IIS the setting can be set on the AppPool like it was traditionally.